# MySQL Slow INSERT on related big tables, 100% CPU use

Tags: mysql, indexing, insert, innodb, insert-update

I am building a website (LAMP stack) with an Amazon RDS MySQL instance as the back end (type db.m3.medium).

I am happy with database integrity, and it works perfectly with regards to SELECT/JOIN/ETC queries (everything is normalized, indexed, and foreign keyed, all tables have id primary keys and relevant secondary keys / unique keys).

I have a table 'df_products' with approx half a million products in it. The products need to be updated nightly. The process involves a PHP script reading over a large products data-file and inserting data into several tables (products table, product_colours table, brands table, etc), calling either INSERT or UPDATE depending on whether or not a row already exists. This is done as one giant transaction.

What I am seeing is the UPDATE commands are sufficiently fast (50/sec, not exactly lightning but it should do), however the INSERT commands are super slow (1/sec) and appear to be consuming 100% of the CPU. On a dual core instance we see 50% CPU use (i.e. one full core).
I assume that this is because indexes (1x PRIMARY + 5x INDEX + 1x UNIQUE + 1x FULLTEXT) are being rebuilt after every INSERT. However I though that putting the entire process into one transaction should stop indexes being rebuilt until the transaction is committed.

I have tried setting the following params via PHP but there is negligible performance improvement:

```
$this->db->query('SET unique_checks=0');
$this->db->query('SET foreign_key_checks=0;');
```

The process will take weeks to complete at this rate so we must improve performance. Google appears to suggest using LOAD DATA. However:

- I would have to generate five files in order to populate five tables
- The process would have to use UPDATE commands as opposed to INSERT since the tables already exist
- I would still need to loop over the products and scan the database for what values already do and don't exist

The database is entirely InnoDB and I don't plan to move to MyISAM (I want transactions, foreign keys, etc). This means that I cannot disable indexes. Even if I did it would probably be a big performance drain as we need to check if a row already exists before we insert it, and without an index this will be super slow.

I have provided the products table defition below for information. Can you please provide advice to what process we should be using to achieve faster INSERT/UPDATE on multiple large related tables? Or what optimisations we can make to our existing process?

Thank you,

```
CREATE TABLE `df_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_brand` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_gender` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_colourSet` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seoAlias` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `runTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `seoAlias_UNIQUE` (`seoAlias`),
  KEY `idx_brand` (`id_brand`),
  KEY `idx_category` (`id_category`),
  KEY `idx_seoAlias` (`seoAlias`),
  KEY `idx_colourSetId` (`id_colourSet`),
  KEY `idx_timestamp` (`runTimestamp`),
  KEY `idx_gender` (`id_gender`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_title` (`title`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_colourSet` FOREIGN KEY (`id_colourSet`) REFERENCES `df_productcolours` (`id_colourSet`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_gender` FOREIGN KEY (`id_gender`) REFERENCES `df_lu_genders` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=285743 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: The FULLTEXT index is what is really slowing you down. I suggest to update your data model so that the title column is not in the products table anymore and can be managed separately (by batch update of your index or other style).

Comment: Dropping the FULLTEXT index has improved performance from approx 1 row /sec to 1.5 row/sec. This is still far too slow for our requirements

Comment: Hum, I have used worse indexing then this. Any triggers on insert which are executed?

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :) There are no triggers on the table

Comment: Did you follow these conditions in your insert actions:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: Yes, the check conditions are in my first code snippet, the entire procedure is wrapped in a transaction, thereby autocommit is inherently set to zero. However, the multi-row INSERT is complicated due to the table relation

Answer (score 0):

How many "genders" are there?  If the usual 2, don't normalize it, don't index it, don't us a 4-byte INT to store it, use a `CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET ascii` (only 1 byte) or an ENUM (1 byte).

Each unnecessary index is a performance drain on the load, regardless of how it is done.

For `INSERT` vs `UPDATE`, look into using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Load the nightly data into a separate table (this could be MyISAM with no indexes).  Then run one query to update existing rows and one to insert new rows.  (Each needs a `JOIN`.)  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table, especially the 2 SQLs used for "normalizing".  They can be adapted to your situation.

Any kind of multi-row query runs noticeably faster than 1-row at a time.  (A 100-row INSERT runs 10 times as fast as 100 1-row inserts.)

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` will let the *individual* write statements run much faster.  (Batching them as I suggest won't speed up much.)

Comment: Thanks, do you think our present slowness comes from the rebuilding of indexes after every INSERT?

Comment: Perhaps.  I would _not_ turn off FKs and UNIQUE checks.  (You did not say how you are "rebuilding the indexes".)

Comment: What I mean is, doesn't the database re-calculate all indexes on a table after an insert?

Comment: No.  Indexes are maintained incrementally.  When you add one item to a filing cabinet, you place where it belongs.  You don't throw all the items on the floor, shuffle them around, and then re-sort them.

Comment: However, you are talking about inserting lots of rows.  In an extreme, it _may_ be more efficient to throw everything on the floor.  But don't do it that way unless you have benchmarked both ways.

Comment: When an item is inserted into a balanced binary tree the entire tree needs to be rebuilt. I assumed that indexes are implemented as balanced binary trees. If not, how are they implemented?

Comment: Virtually all indexes in MySQL are BTrees, not Binary Trees.  The BTrees are never "rebuilt" as a result of INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE.  There will be cases of "block split" and "recombining blocks".